# How can I set the alignment for individual axis labels in highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I would like the ability to set a different text alignment for the first and last labels on my x axis. For all the labels in between, I would like the labels to be center aligned.

```
|______________________________________________________|
|          |          |          |          |          |
Jun 2    Jun 3      Jun 4      Jun 5      Jun 6    Jun 7
```

In the example above

- The first tick (Jun 2) is left aligned
- The last tick (Jun 7) is right aligned
- All ticks in between are center aligned

From what I can see in the documentation I am limited to a single [`align` setting](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.labels.align) which applies to all tick labels.

Has anyone found a workaround for this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [overflow](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.overflow) parameter as 'justify'

```
labels:{
    overflow: 'justify'
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/0aq6o5vv/1/

Comment: This is perfect. I can't believe I missed this in the documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately this property is now deprecated. Anyone have a solution for the latest version of Highcharts, 5.x + ?

Answer (score 0):

Can't find anything in the API that'll let you customize to that level, so here's my hack:

```
   chart: {
        events: {
            load: function(){
                var fL = this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.firstChild;
                var lL = this.xAxis[0].labelGroup.element.lastChild;
                fL.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(fL.getAttribute('x')) + fL.getBBox().width / 2);
                lL.setAttribute('x', parseFloat(lL.getAttribute('x')) - lL.getBBox().width / 2);
            }
        }
    },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cmp7faLL/).

Won't work with the VML fallback though.

Comment: This might be a workable solution. I played around with it a bit and re-used this function for the `redraw` event as well.  http://jsfiddle.net/0aq6o5vv/